# Android TreeMap blues... Are there alternatives?

Tags: java, android, treemap

I've been trying to use TreeMaps on Android and ran into the following two issues:

1. Missing methods on older Android systems:
   When I try to run my app on my Android 2.2.2 test-device, it greets me with 
   `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.TreeMap.lowerEntry`
   Why? According to 
   [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/java/util/TreeMap.html), TreeMap should be supported since API 1, no?
2. Absolutely abysmal performance on other devices (NOT TRUE, SEE UPDATE!):
   Even on very small trees with only 100 elements or so, operations take on the order of milli-seconds (!) to complete. Ouch...

Basically, I need a data structure that provides a super-fast map, "indexed" by a sparse integer-key (e.g. it contains entries for keys 2, 100, 29392, 399391, ...). It needs to be able to quickly perform the following operations:

- Add an entry to the map associated with an arbitrary integer key
- Find the entry associated with some integer key (or null if none found)
- Remove the key-entry pair from the map for a given key
- Iterate over the entries in the map
- Clear the map
- Return the entry corresponding to the largest key less than (or equal to) some number
- Return the entry corresponding to the smallest key bigger than or equal to some number

So, basically I need TreeMap's `get`, `put`, `remove`, `values`, `clear`, `ceilingEntry` or `higherEntry`, and `lowerEntry` or `floorEntry`. (For the last two either option is ok as one can be turned into the other simply by incrementing or decrementing the reference key by 1)

Are there any alternatives to TreeMap that perform well and are available either on all Android devices or I can include in my app?

**UPDATE:**
I need to apologize to Android or whoever was involved in building the TreeMap: Due to some stupid logic-mistake, I was calling the TreeMap methods a whole bunch more times than I thought. The performance is actually perfectly fine. I was just being retarded... So, point 2 no longer is a concern. Leaves point 1. Sorry, everyone...

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/FastTreeMap.html

Comment: as for #1,   copy this into your app https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/master/luni/src/main/java/java/util/TreeMap.java

Comment: `TreeMap`, the *class*, was added in API Level 1. `lowerEntry()`, the *method*, [was added in API Level 9](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeMap.html#lowerEntry%28K%29).

Comment: You may wanna give this one a try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html

Comment: @petey "If you are creating and accessing a TreeMap only within a single thread, you should use java.util.TreeMap directly (with no synchronization), for maximum performance." Hmmm... sounds like this could be even worse, at least in my single-threaded setup... But it would solve the availability issue...

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh... I missed that... Whoops...  Thanks...

Comment: @JohanShogun Looks interesting, but from the description it sounds like it might perform very poorly, especially since I'd have to somehow hack the `ceilingEntry`, ... methods...

Comment: @MarkusA. if I were to look at the class I would probably look into sub classing it and adding the code necessary for a fast ceilingEntry method.

Comment: `ceilingEntry` can be emulated by taking `tailMap(key).entrySet().iterator().next()`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman DUDE! Awesome catch! :) That should work! (Why can't I upvote your comment?) If you like, why don't you write up a quick answer that explains this idea and I will accept it! (See update to question that I will post in a second... :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emulate some of the `NavigableMap` methods with some trickery.  For example, `ceilingEntry` is approximately equivalent to `tailMap(key).entrySet().iterator().next()`, though it'll throw if there is no entry instead of returning null.  (Just use `hasNext()` on the iterator to work around that.)

`lowerEntry` is harder; you can do `headMap(key).lastKey()` and call `get` on that to get the whole entry.  `higherEntry` and `floorEntry` are harder still, but you've said that's not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Missing methods on older Android systems:

you can backport it yourself by copying the code into your app from 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/master/luni/src/main/java/java/util/TreeMap.java

> 2. Absolutely abysmal performance on other devices:

Try using 
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/FastTreeMap.html

Perhaps a little bit of both will get you in better shape.

HTHs